# Files do not download completely or get corrupted

Tags: android, download

I have an Android app that downloads files from a `Tomcat7 running on RedHat Linux` server occasionally as needed.  The server is under my control and only authorized users can download.  The files are database information and can be quite large, as much as 4.8Mb.  However, even tiny files fail to download fully.

These files have downloaded fine in the past, but recently started to fail to download completely.  I don't know if the problem is on the server or client side yet.  Server bandwidth usage ~10%.

I am looking for guidance on how to determine if it's a server problem, or a problem in the Android app. I have searched for hours trying to find anything that may be related without success.

**I don't know if it's related, but SecureCopy (SCP) stalls frequency on this server.**

Comment: You might want to mention the server and database types and versions.

Comment: When downloading fails you should have an error message both on client and server side. Can you show it?

Comment: No errors.  The file just does not download fully.

Comment: @M.A.Kishawy  I updated my post.  No database involved.

Comment: To decide if the issue is server side or client side, I would make a simple web app to see if you can get the files download or not.

Comment: @M.A.Kishawy  I just remembered that an update to the web site went out when this all started.  In that update, the directories were moved from `WEB_INF/somedirectory` to an external directory where `Tomcat user` is `owner`.  Perhaps this is related?

Comment: I really can't tell for sure. You need to have some logging in your app to catch any failure happening. However access right issue would prevent you from getting the download started in the first place. So I would assume it's something else. I would try to eliminate the possibilities by trying first to decide if the issue is client or server side.